# /usr/bin/svnadd legit or malicious?

Tags: bash, files, ossec

I installed OSSEC, and the following file failed a rootkit check. I'm not sure if it's malicious or what it's doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The file is a bash file: /usr/bin/svnadd
Below are its contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
svn status | perl -ne 's/^\?\s+(\S.+)$/\1/g;chomp;system("svn add \"$_\"");'
```

The version of Ubuntu we're running is a fully patched 10.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Note that 10.04 is end-of-life and no longer supported (in terms of support or security updates), and I recommend that you upgrade to 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is legitimate but poorly written.  Its purpose is to put files under version control, using `subversion`, also called `svn`, if they are not already control.

Suppose, for example, that subversion reports the following about your current directory:

```
$ svn status
?       something.c
M       other.h
```

This means that `something.c` is not currently under version control.  `other.h` is under version control but the local copy have been modified (hence the `M`).

Your svnadd command will cause the following commands to be executed:

```
svn add something.c
svn add M       other.h
```

The first places `something.c` under version control.  The second command attempts to place the files `M` and `other.h` under version control.  Since `other.h` is already under version control, this will generate an error.  What happens with `M` depends on whether there is a file called `M` in your directory.

In sum, this command is not malicious.  It will not infect anything.  But, don't run it.